# " The EC2 instance did not turn into the expected unused state in target group" AWS Code deploy error

Tags: amazon-web-services, hook, aws-code-deploy

I have tried to use code deploy and it works perfectly when I don't use any ALB. however, when I try to use an ALB the deployment got stuck on the block traffic hooks. I tried to decrease the Deregistration time of the target group from 300 to 60 sec. also, try to configure the health check and lower the default value of the interval from 30 to 5, and the healthy threshold from 5 to 2. Also reinstall the code deploy agent but nothing works and still got stuck on the block traffic hooks. after 1-hour code deploy get the error "The EC2 instance did not turn into the expected unused state in target group". how to solve this issue?

Is there any workaround for this case?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue right now.